# Applying a date function to a column to extract out date attributes

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime

I'm trying to build a customer function in python that can handle a variety of date related tasks so its easy for me to use in a variety of circumstances.

I'm seeming to struggle with how to apply this to an entire column.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates' : ['2018-01-02','2018-06-15','2018-07-07']}) 


def get_date_attribute(date_attribute,date_field):

    """
    Take in a date in YYYY-MM-DD format and return the month
    """

    mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_field, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if date_attribute =='month':
        result = mydate.month()
    elif date_attribute =='year':
        result = mydate.year()
    elif date_attribute=='day':
        result = mydate.day()
    else:
        print("Valid values: 'month','day','year'")

    return(result)


df['month']= df.apply(get_date_attribute(date_attribute='month',date_field='dates'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize this. Define a function that

1. converts the field column to datetime, and
2. dynamically extracts the attribute of interest using `getattr`

Now, apply this function via `DataFrame.pipe`.

```
def get_date_attr(df, attr, field):
     return getattr(
         pd.to_datetime(df[field], errors='coerce').dt, attr)
```

```
df.pipe(get_date_attr, attr='month', field='dates')

0    1
1    6
2    7
Name: dates, dtype: int64

df.pipe(get_date_attr, attr='day', field='dates')

0     2
1    15
2     7
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: IMO it would be an even nicer example if you would chain a few `DF.pipe`'s together... ;-)